# Можно ли вернуть значение функции в переменную являющуюся аргументом этой функции?

Tags: python, функции

```
a= 2
b = 3

def test(val):
   val += 2
   return val

test(a)
test (b)

print (a) #результат должен быть 4
print (b) #результат должен быть 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передача аргументов в python работает также, как присваивание.

- Если ты передаешь переменную *изменяемого типа* (list, set, dict) в функцию, функция получает ссылку на сам объект, с которым можно делать все, что душе будет угодно и после завершения функции в контексте вызова переменные будут хранить ссылки на уже измененный объект. Но если внутри функции перепривязать к локальной переменной ссылку на другой объект, контекст вызова ничего об этом не узнает, а после завершения функции, исходная переменная будет содержать ту же самую ссылку, какая была до вызова.
- Если ты передаешь объект *неизменяемого типа* (int, float, str, tuple...) в функцию, ты по-прежнему не можешь перепривязать ссылку из контекста вызова функции, но и изменить сам объект у тебя тоже не получится.

Попробую это прояснить на примере из вопроса же:

### `int` - неизменяемый тип

```
a = 2

def test(val):
   val += 2
   return val # в переменной val будет 4

test(a)
print(a) #результат будет 2
```

`a` - это ссылка на объект `2`. При вызове `test` локальная переменная `val` тоже ссылается на этот объект. Когда мы делаем `val += 2`, или, то же самое, что `val = val + 2`, мы конструируем объект `4` и ссылку на него кладем в `val`.

Однако после выхода из функции ссылка `a` по-прежнему указывает на объект `2`.

### Как же можно, все-таки, добиться желаемого поведения?

Просто вернуть значение, ну это очевидно:

```
a = 2

def test(val):
   val += 2
   return val

a = test(a)

print(a) #результат будет 4
```

Вспомним "The zen of python" - явное лучше, чем неявное. Поэтому этот способ наиболее предпочтителен.

Но если, действительно, ну очень хочется избежать явного возврата значения из функции и изменять само значение прямо в теле функции, можно использовать ключевое слово `global`. Однако, это троянский конь в истинном смысле, неизвестно какие ошибки в программе он может породить. Здравствуйте бессонные ночи отладки. Не рекомендуется.

А еще можно обернуть значение в изменяемый тип данных - например, список:

```
a = [2]

def test(val):
   val[0] += 2

test(a)

print(a[0]) #результат будет 4
```

Но если каждый раз так писать? Выглядит громоздко, на мой взгляд.

Использованные ресурсы:

- [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)
- [How do I write a function with output parameters (call by reference)?](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference)

Comment: Спасибо очень развернутый и полезный ответ. Однако мне все-же интересно как с помощью global можно получить имя передаваемой переменной внутри функции? Да я могу явно указать globals()['a'] но хотелось бы чтобы функция сама получала это имя в зависимости от имени переменной которую я ей передаю.

Comment: Для такого сценарий, пожалуй, только использовать изменяемые обертки. Ударяясь в дискуссию, можно начать спрашивать, а чем это лучше, чем явно вернуть значение и все такое.

Comment: Я понимаю, зачем передача по ссылке в С++, одна из важных причин, чтобы из функции вернуть несколько значений - надо очень серьезно поприседать. В python можно за один раз вернуть сколько душе угодно значений.

Comment: Извиняюсь за ссылку на английском, но [How to get the original variable name of variable passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749810).